# Reachability in one device return "NotReachable" despite have a 4G

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability, internet-connection, 4g

I have in my app check with Reachability check, but in one device in 4G its return me a NotReachable even the iPhone get Facebook messages and whatsapp.

if the iPhone in wifi this work grate.

what can be the problem ?

```
-(BOOL)isConnectedToInternet {
Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:HOST_NAME];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
return networkStatus != NotReachable;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the Reachability framework. I can recommand using  AFNetworking / AFNetworkReachabilityManager. I never had any problem with it and I know for a fact, that it is reliable

Comment: Please check in settings that, is mobile data on for your app

Comment: thanks I try now AFNetworking and when the user response me I update here.

Comment: ya same issue with Reachability but you can use default SCNetworkReachability provided by systemconfiguration framework. If you want method I can post my answer with this default method.

Comment: Reachability is just sample code which wraps `SCNetworkReachability` in ObjC code.

Answer (score 3):

I have always had problems with Reachability. I tend not to use it now and just make the network call. `AFNetworking` will fail with an `NSError` with code `kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` (-1009) if there's no network.